# Create Dictionary for unique value source for Combobox - add another column source

Tags: excel, vba, loops, dictionary, filter

Hi I have  combobox which works fine for filtering using the below code:

```
    Dim rCell As Range

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
       For Each rCell In ws.Range("N3", ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp))
          If Not .Exists(rCell.Value) And Not rCell.Value = "" Then
             .Add rCell.Value, Nothing
          End If
    Next rCell

    ComboBox4.List = .keys
    End With
```

All works as expected. All I now want to do is add column K to a second column in my Combobox. This column is more so the user knows the description. Column N is a unique list of Project Numbers and my requirement is just to show against that Project Number its associated description into the 2nd column of the combobox. Is this possible?

Thankyou

Comment: Let me understand what is your real need, please: Do you want to collect from K:K the corespondent value of N:N (the same row), of the **first occurrence**? Should be this understanding correct? Do your unique values have the same description in all occurrences?

Comment: Every row will have a Project ID and a corresponding description. Ive just missed and essential bit uf information in that where Column C has a value of 1 then take that Project number and Descpription.

Comment: So, the value from K:K should be used **only if in column C:C a 1 value exists**. Not the first occurrence of the unique key. Is this understanding correct? If yes, this needs a different approach. I can do it, but I could see that you did not understand my code and prefer the variant loading the combo item by item...

Comment: Thankyou for your support and being honest I'm not a coder. I'm a PLM consultant who needs to provide a solution from data exported into excel and using VBA post process the extracted data. If you looked at all the code ive put together you would fall off your seat laughing......its shocking but it works and more importantly im learning VBA and really enjoying it. Im happy with some pointers and working the code myself honestly but I am grateful for your support. looking for is scan row C until the end and IF you hit a cell value which equals 1 then show the value of

Comment: Then, try the code I posted. It should do what (I understand) you need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub LoadComboTwoColumnsCond()
  Dim rCell As Range, ws As Worksheet, arr

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
       For Each rCell In ws.Range("N3", ws.cells(rows.count, "N").End(xlUp))
          If Not .Exists(rCell.value) And rCell.Offset(0, -11).value = 1 And rCell.value <> "" Then
                .Add rCell, rCell.Offset(0, -3).value 'add the K:K correspondent like item value
          End If
      Next rCell
      arr = Application.Transpose(Array(.Keys, .items)) 'create a 2D array with two columns from dictionary keys/items
   End With
    
    With ComboBox4
        .ColumnCount = 2 'set number of columns to be shown
        .list = arr      'put the array in the list property
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want more than 2 columns

```vb
    Dim i As Long
    ComboBox1.Clear
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
       For Each rCell In ws.Range("N3", ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp))
          If Not .Exists(rCell.Value) And Not rCell.Value = "" Then
             .Add rCell.Value, Nothing
             ComboBox1.AddItem rCell
             ComboBox1.List(i, 1) = rCell.Offset(0, -3) 'K
             'ComboBox1.List(i, 2) = rCell.Offset(0, -2) 'L
             i = i + 1
          End If
       Next rCell
    End With

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim i As Long
    If ComboBox1.ListCount < 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        i = ComboBox1.ListIndex
        MsgBox "Selected " & ComboBox1.List(i, 0) & " " & ComboBox1.List(i, 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou so much exactly what ive been trying to achieve :-) Only issue now is when I select I see the unique Project Numbers with Descriptions but when I select a row from the combobox drop down list it returns blank. Sorry for being thick :-)